# Keras load_model

Tags: python, keras

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iz7eG.jpg)

My keras saving model code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0LLM.jpg)

my keras version: 2.2.2
Max OS.

i can load other's model via model = keras.models.load_model("model.h5"), but cannot load my own model via the same code. by the way, i can use other computer to load my model. so, what wrong with my mac?

Comment: Did you try loading it from another environment in your PC?

Comment: Please, for the love of god, put written code here and no pictures. From the looks of it, you are saving your model as `model1.h5`, but try to load `model.h5`.

Comment: sorry for that. this is the first time i use stackoverflow. What you said cannot solve the problem.  i change my model name to model1.h5. If i load model with wrong name, the Pycharm will raise an error with no found "model.h5", not TypeError.

Answer (score 0):

Try save the weights with `save_weights` function:

```
model.save_weights('model.h5')
```

Then, to load it just use:

```
model.load_weights('model.h5')
```